# Calculating number of non-duplicated permutation

Tags: permutations

I want to calculate the number of permutation from duplicated list.

Example) There is a list combined of 76 icons.

Here is icon list

A: 1
B: 3
C: 5
D: 6
E: 6
F: 5
G: 10
H: 9
I: 8
J: 7
K: 6
L: 10

In this List, I want to pick 3 icon and make a permutation list without duplication. 
For example (B,B,C), (C,B,B), (B,C,B) will be counted as different case.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  If you don't use $A$, how many choices do you have for each slot?  You have enough of each that you won't run out.  If you do use $A$, put it somewhere, then fill the other slots.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. If it's not bothering you, can I get it as math formula?